# Can I use prefix and suffix in amazon s3 event as regex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, event-handling

I need my event to run when a file with the name `ABC-XXXX-input.csv` is loaded on the bucket where `XXXX` is a number and is variable.

So I assumed that all I need to do is to properly complete the prefix and suffix as follows:

prefix = `ABC-`

suffix = `input.csv`

however, after uploading the file, the lambda attached to the event does not run.

I checked for the settings:

prefix = ''

suffix = `input.csv`

I uploaded the input.csv file and the event started normally, so it seems that the lambda startup itself is configured correctly.

Am I doing something wrong with the prefix and suffix settings?

I found some answers on stack but all from 2016-2018 and maybe something is difference now?

Comment: Are you adding a common prefix to the object names?  Something like "`object/name/ABC-XXXX-input.csv`" ?